# using two ' = ?' in a clause

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm using python(3.5.1) and I want to update the Player_score field on the relevant row for only that player (selected via player name(these are unique but not the primary key)). I've been trying to get it to work like this for a while now but no avail and i can't think of any other way to get it to work. Any help would be great and working code would be fantastic - thanks xx

```
def End_Game(Score, Name):
Score = str(Score)
print("Final Score for", Name, "was:", Score)
with sqlite3.connect("Highscores.db") as db:
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("UPDATE Highscores SET Player_Score = ? WHERE Player_Name = ? ", Score, Name)
```

i get the error message: 
`TypeError: function takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)`but if i remove one of the references (just straight up remove it from the end of the clause) it says:
`sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 2, and there are 1 supplied.`

so again if anyone can help or advise i would most appreciate it. I'm hoping this is a simple fix and i've simply forgotten something.xx

******Since, posting - adding ' ' around the ? for Player_Name Stops error messages but the table still doesn't update. Any help why would be great - same goes for first question still, though. xx

Comment: You need `(Score, Name)` to pass as a single object. Put them in a tuple. So `cursor.execute("UPDATE Highscores SET Player_Score = ? WHERE Player_Name = ? ", (Score, Name))`

Comment: as roganjosh told you, you need to pass all _data_ that replaces the `?` inside one tuple - not `cursor.execute("sql", Score, Name)` but `cursor.execute("sql", (Score, Name) )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the arguments as a tuple, change

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE Highscores SET Player_Score = ? WHERE Player_Name = ? ", Score, Name)
```

to

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE Highscores SET Player_Score = ? WHERE Player_Name = ? ", (Score, Name))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use execute method as :
cursor.execute("UPDATE Highscores SET Player_Score = ? WHERE Player_Name = ? ", (Score, Name,))